# Selenium IDE Chrome - Regex

Tags: selenium, automation, ide

I am trying to get Selenium IDE to check some text and make sure it is Numbers Only, I have created the below (using Google) and it seems to fail each time.

Error :
assertText on css=tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) with value regexpi:^[0-9]+$ Failed:
09:44:54
Actual value "10640355" did not match "regexpi:^[0-9]+$"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzPaE.png)

Can anyone tell me what I need to change, or have a step by step guide on how to add this check properly

Answer (score 1):

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands#assert-text

Regex is not supported for assert text:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/issues/141 for details.

**Workaround:**

**screenshot**

[image]

**code:**

```
store text   |   css=tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1)  |  actualText

execute script  |   return RegExp('^[0-9]+$','g').test(${actualText})  |  isNumber

assert       |     isNumber      |     true
```